# Why the launch browser option of sublime xdebug is missing?

Tags: xdebug, sublimetext3

When I press `ctrl + shift + p` and press `xd` ,there is only `start debug` option,Why the `start debug launch browser` is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the current .sublime-project file and save the project again.

Project -> Save Project As...

Then insert again in the .sublime-project file the code below:

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
        "follow_symlinks": true,
        "path": "."
    }
  ],
  "settings": {
    "xdebug": {
         "url": "http://my.local.website/",
    }
  }
}
```

** Be sure to change the "url" to your site base URL.